# Enable time bound access to Azure Resources

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

We want to give user an elevated permission to specific azure resources for limited time. User can ask for access with subscription name and resource group or resource and hours it needs access.

Example:
`GrantAccess -sub 673vh3h3h666 -rg myrg -t 6h`

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with [Azure AD entitlement management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/governance/entitlement-management-access-package-first).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/governance/entitlement-management-overview

> What can I do with entitlement management?

> Control who can get access to applications, groups, Teams and SharePoint sites, with multi-stage approval, and ensure users don't retain access indefinitely through time-limited assignments and recurring access reviews.

> Delegate to non-administrators the ability to create access packages. These access packages contain resources that users can request, and the delegated access package managers can define policies with rules for which users can request, who must approve their access, and when access expires.

> Select connected organizations whose users can request access. When a user who isn't yet in your directory requests access, and is approved, they're automatically invited into your directory and assigned access. When their access expires, if they have no other access package assignments, their B2B account in your directory can be automatically removed.

[Create a new access package in Azure AD entitlement management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/governance/entitlement-management-access-package-create)